# Can we register a custom handlebars helper written on an external file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, handlebars.js

I am trying to implement Handlebars templates in my app. My query is, can we load and register  a custom handlebar helper written on an external file?

The following code works fine, however the helper is within the page.

```
$.post(baseURL,
    {
        struser:UserName,
        password:Password,
        alias:"GetData",
        parameters:""
    },
    function(data,status){
        if(status="success"){

            Handlebars.registerHelper('MenuHelper', function() {
                if(this.NextLevel == 1){
                    return '<a href="' + this.url + '">' + this.text + '</a>';
                };
            });

            var vdata = JSON.parse(data);
            var template = Handlebars.templates['ListMenu.tmpl'];
            $("#listItem").html(template(vdata));
            $("#listItem").listview("refresh");
        }else{
            alert(connectionError);
        };
    });
};
```

I wanted to move this piece of code to a separate file and register it in the main file whenever required.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('MenuHelper', function() {
    if(this.NextLevel == 1){
        return '<a href="' + this.url + '">' + this.text + '</a>';
    };
});
```

Not sure how to get this thing done. Tried adding this to the template file, but was not successful. Can you please help me out with this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can someone please help me out... any kindly of head way is fine

Comment: A handler is just a function so what's the problem?

Comment: I am very new to Handlebars, so was not sure how exactly this Handlebars.registerHelper works. Thanks a ton for your hint. I have got this done. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My enthusiasm fired by Mr. "mu is too short"'s direction, lead me to this solution :-D

I have created this function in a separate file

```
function MenuHelper() {
    if(this.NextLevel == 1){
        return '<a href="' + this.url + '">' + this.text + '</a>';
    };
});
```

and registered the helper in the main file using this single line

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("MenuHelper", MenuHelper);
```

This is how my complete code looks like. Again thanks a ton to Mr. "mu is too short"

```
$.post(baseURL,
    {
        struser:UserName,
        password:Password,
        alias:"GetData",
        parameters:""
    },
    function(data,status){
        if(status="success"){
            Handlebars.registerHelper("MenuHelper", MenuHelper);
            var vdata = JSON.parse(data);
            var template = Handlebars.templates['ListMenu.tmpl'];
            $("#listItem").html(template(vdata));
            $("#listItem").listview("refresh");
        }else{
            alert(connectionError);
        };
    });
};
```